# Stream vs Iterator for an API with paging

Tags: java, rest, api, java-stream

Given a web API with paging that returns **more** items than can fit in memory at any one time

```
HTTP GET /items?start=0&limit=10
```

I want to construct an easy-to use Java client. A paging client is hard to use

```
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageResut(0,10);
Page<Item> page = client.findItems(page);
while( !page.isLastPage() ) {
   Page<Item> nextPage = client.findItems( page.getNextPage() );
}
```

Hiding the paging client behind either an `Iterator` ..

```
Iterator<Item> items = client.pagingItemsIterator();
// every 10 elements the iterator requests the next page behind the scenes i.e.
// the paging code of above is hidden in an iterator
items.forEachRemaining(this::dostuff);
```

... or a `Stream` makes the API easier to use

```
Stream<Item> items = client.pagingItemsStream();
// every 10 elements the stream requests the next page behind the scenes
// i.e. the paging code above is hidden in the stream supplier
items.forEach(this::dostuff);
```

A `Stream` is more versatile. Is there anything in how a stream is intended to be used that makes it unsuitable for this use case ? Like:

- Does a stream assume all items are known, compared to requesting the next page behind the scenes when the last item in the stream is fetched?
- Is it against good practices of streams, that request item #11 can fail with a `RuntimeException` because a new page request is performed to get items in the next page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to make this as a comment, but sort of was too big.

> Does a stream assume all items are known...

Look at `Files::lines` for example, there is no way to know the exact number of lines that are in a certain file, so the underlying implementation somehow does that... For sequential stream that is easy, for a parallel one - all they do is buffer until at least `1024` lines are buffered (+ 1024 in the next buffer and so on). So yes, a stream implementation without a known size is absolutely possible, even if that size can change dynamically - though this brings a lot of other problems too IMO.

> Is it against good practices of streams, that request item #11 can fail with a RuntimeException because a new page request is performed to get items in the next page?

Not very sure I understand this fully, but it seems that you are concerned with multiple simultaneous requests to the same data. If so, this isn't normal to me for streams as much as it is not normal for *just* the `PageRequest`; after all you just read data - if it's not there, return an empty list or partial list or whatever, but don't throw an Exception. If the underlying `PageRequest` throws that, treat it in the wrapper that you will have anyway.

Just notice that generally you can transform very easily from a `Iterator -> Stream` and from `Stream -> Iterator` if needed. Even so, I would stick with a `Stream` approach if you can implement it.